# Switch background in CSS when browser or device gets to a certain width

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have an image as the background of the main content area and the side bar. It is responsive and works well until the side bar disappears to the bottom. Then I would like to switch the background to a different image that doesn't have the side bar color anymore.

I am working on WordPress and can edit the CSS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to use a media query. A piece of CSS that can only be seen once a condition has been met. For example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

Where any screen less than 500px is when the background will be blue.

Comment: I would like to use another image as the background. I tried using a url, but must have done it wrong. The white worked great!

Comment: Using an image you would simply have to change the 'background:blue;' to 'background: URL("../path/to/IMG.png");'